# Regex match with text box

Tags: c#, regex, string, textbox

I try to search in my list elements with pattern

```
string pat = @"(a)"; // works
```

But when I try to use textbox to set pattern it doesent works

```
//string pat = @"("+textBox1.ToString()+")"; // not works
```

Someone have any idea? I try do it on diffrent ways and nothing works :(

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string text = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match m = r.Match(text);
}
```

Comment: Also, learn to use the debugger and check what the value of `pat` is... that value should give you a pretty big hint to the problem

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Could you give us full story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `textBox1.Text` instead of `textBox1.ToString()`

```
string pat = "("+textBox1.Text+")";
```

or if you use C# 6.0 or above then

```
string pat = $"({textBox1.Text})";
```

Comment: Also, the `@`is not need as this will only affect the first string and there is nothing to escape